# Why my /usr/share/file/magic is not loaded, in PHP at CentOS?

Tags: centos

This is what I'm doing:

```
$ php
<?php
$finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, '/usr/share/file/magic');
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: description `8-bit ISDN mu-law compressed (CCITT G.721 ADPCM voice data enco' truncated in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: description `8-bit ISDN mu-law compressed (CCITT G.721 ADPCM voice data enco' truncated in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: <= not supported in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: <= not supported in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: <= not supported in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  finfo_open(): Warning: >= not supported in - on line 2
PHP Warning:  finfo_open(): Failed to load magic database at '/usr/share/file/magic'. in - on line 2
```

This is a clean CentOS 5.5 installation, PHP 5.3. The file `/usr/share/file/magic` exists and is accessible.

Comment: To be clear: the file `/usr/share/file/magic` is found and parsed by PHP. There are only parse errors (or more precisely warnings).

Comment: Exactly, but this warning is annoying in the log file...